# Why is it necessary to "free" a node?

Tags: c, linked-list

You are given a pointer/ reference to the node which is to be deleted from the linked list of N nodes.

```
Input:
N = 2,
value[] = {1,2},
node = 1 ,
Output: 2
```

I am writing code like this -

```
void deleteNode(Node *del)
{
    del->data=(del->next)->data;
    del->next=(del->next)->next;
}
```

But the given answer is -

```
void deleteNode(Node *del) {    
    Node* temp = del->next;
    del->data = temp->data;
    del->next = temp->next;
    free(temp);
}
```

Both the answers are correct , but i don't know whether my method is wrong or right?

Comment: Both codes have an issue in that they don't check if `next` is `NULL`.

Comment: But re your question: every call to `malloc` should have a corresponding call to `free`. Otherwise, you may eventually run out of memory.

Comment: Actually in question it was written that next would not be NULL . Is my way of writing correct?

Comment: @JohnnyMopp This assumes that the nodes are allocated using `malloc`. It's quite possible to pre-build a pool of them in which case the `free` should not be done. The unstated assumption is at the root of the problem here.

Comment: @ClickRick Since OP states the "given answer" (presumably by the instructor) has the call to `free()`, I think it is safe to assume it was created with `malloc()`.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp Presumably that possibility was excluded because if `next` is null you cannot "delete" `del` that way with a singly linked list. (`del`, despite its name, is never deleted; it is overwritten, and `next` is deleted.)

Comment: To delete a node, just copy the next node into it. If you draw this out, then it is apparent that this is wasteful.

Answer (score 1):

> You are given a pointer/ reference to the node which is to be deleted from the linked list of N nodes.

The description does not match the given answer. For the given answer, the parameter is a pointer to the node just before the node to be deleted. This would be more clear if the function were written as:

```
void deleteNode(Node *prior) {    
    Node* current = prior->next;    /* current = pointer of node to be deleted */
    if(current == NULL)             /* exit if there is no current node */
        return;
    prior->next = current->next;    /* remove node from list */
    free(current);                  /* only if node was allocated with malloc */
}

/* this line is a mistake, so I removed it */
    prior->data = current-> data
```

The problem with this is the first node can't be deleted, unless there is a head | dummy node that points to the first node of a list. An alternative is to use a pointer to pointer to node:

```
/* from the calling code */
    Node **ppdel;
    /* ... */
    ppdel = &head;                  /* if removing 1st node on list */
/* ... or  ... */
    ppdel = &(prior->next)          /* for all but 1st node on list */
    deleteNode(Node **ppdel);
/* ... */
void deleteNode(Node **ppdel) {    
    Node* current = *ppdel;         /* current = pointer of node to be deleted */
    if(current == NULL)             /* exit if there is no current node */
        return;
    *ppdel = current->next;         /* remove node from list */
    free(current);                  /* only if node was allocated with malloc */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a memory leak. That means that the memory allocated for the node  (presumably by `malloc`) is not `free`d in `deleteNode`, but the references to it are. The consequence is that your program could run out of memory eventually and crash.